# Formatting a list

Tags: lisp, format, common-lisp

I have the following list: `(X X O NIL NIL O NIL NIL O)`

I'd like to format it to look like this:

```
X | X | O
--+---+--
  |   | O
--+---+--
  |   | O
```

I could probably cobble something together with what little I know about Lisp and `FORMAT`, but it would probably be pretty gross. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just do it. Worry about fixing the grossness once you have a version that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
* (format t "~{~A | ~A | ~A~%~^--+---+--~%~}"
    (mapcar (lambda (x) (or x " ")) '(X O X NIL X X O X NIL)))
X | O | X
--+---+--
  | X | X
--+---+--
O | X |
NIL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* (format t "~{~A | ~A | ~A~%~^--+---+--~%~}"
    (mapcar (lambda (x) (or x " ")) '(X O X NIL X X O X NIL)))
X | O | X
--+---+--
  | X | X
--+---+--
O | X |
NIL
```

A little explanation about the format string in the above.  Crucial here are the '~{' '~}' and '~^'.   A pair of matching Tilde braces take a list as input argument and iterate over it.  The ~^ controls an early escape from this loop, if the list being iterated over is empty. 
Relevant documentation [~{](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cgd.htm) and [~^](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cib.htm).